# expected 1 selector or at-rule compiler error

Tags: sass, compiler-errors

I can write in scss this:

```
 :root {
     margin: 0px;
 }
```

but looks I get compiler error when I write in sass same thing:

```
:root
    margin: 0px
```

I just get compiler error: "Error: Invalid CSS after "r": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "root: {"

Answer (score 0):

You can try preprending inverted slash `\:root` or twice dots `::root`